# Android IllegalStateException No instrumentation registered! Must run under a registering instrumentation

Tags: android, android-studio, functional-testing, android-espresso

I am struggling to make this functional test with Espresso work on Android. My App is a Multdex app so I am following the instructions written at this link as follows : (https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html).

I have already configured my build.gradle like this :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'
def AAVersion = '3.3.2'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.4'
    }
}
    apt {
        arguments {
            androidManifestFile variant.outputs[0].processResources.manifestFile
            resourcePackageName 'br.com.foo'
        }
    }

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 21
        buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "br.com.foo"
            minSdkVersion 15
            targetSdkVersion 21
            android.enforceUniquePackageName = false
            multiDexEnabled true
            compileOptions {
                sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
                targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
            }

            testApplicationId "br.com.foo.test"
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
            testInstrumentationRunner "com.android.test.runner.MultiDexTestRunner"
        }

        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            }
        }

        dexOptions {
            preDexLibraries = false
            javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        }

        packagingOptions {
            exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        }
    }

    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force 'com.android.support:support-annotations:22.1.0'}

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        apt "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:$AAVersion"
        compile "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:$AAVersion"
        compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.1.0'
        compile 'com.github.daimajia:AndroidViewAnimations:v1.1.3'
        compile 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.1.1'
        compile 'com.github.ACRA:acra:acra-4.6.2'
        compile 'com.github.rahatarmanahmed:circularprogressview:2.3.2'
        compile 'com.github.jhy:jsoup:jsoup-1.8.3'
        compile project(':cacscore')
        compile project(':croplib')
        compile project(':zxingandroid')
        compile project(':paho')
        compile project(':urlImageViewHelper')
        compile project(':facebookSDK')
        compile project(':googleDateTimePickers')
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
        compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'
        compile files('libs/httpmime-4.1.jar')
        compile files('libs/jackson-all-1.9.11.jar')
        compile files('libs/jaxrs-api-2.2.1.GA.jar')
        compile files('libs/spring-android-core-1.0.1.RELEASE.jar')
        compile files('libs/spring-android-rest-template-1.0.1.RELEASE.jar')
        compile 'com.melnykov:floatingactionbutton:1.2.0'
        compile files('libs/trace.jar')

        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:1.6.2'
        testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4-rule-agent:1.6.2'
        testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4-rule:1.6.2'
        testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.6.2'

        androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    //    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test:testing-support-lib:0.1') {
    //        exclude group: 'junit'  // junit:junit-dep conflicts with junit:unit
    //    }
        androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.4'
        // Set this dependency to use JUnit 4 rules
        androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.4'
        // Set this dependency to build and run Espresso tests
        androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.1'
        // Set this dependency to build and run UI Automator tests
    //    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.uiautomator:uiautomator-v18:2.1.2'

        androidTestCompile('com.android.support:multidex-instrumentation:1.0.1') {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'multidex'
        }
    }
```

I configured the Run profile from the Android Studio setting the testInstrumentationRunner classe to com.android.test.runner.MultiDexTestRunner.

When I execute the command "***adb shell pm list instrumentation***" I have this output:

```
instrumentation:br.com.doe.test/com.android.test.runner.MultiDexTestRunner (target=br.com.doe)
instrumentation:br.com.foo.test/com.android.test.runner.MultiDexTestRunner (target=br.com.foo)
instrumentation:br.com.foo/com.android.test.runner.MultiDexTestRunner (target=br.com.foo)
```

But still I receive this output when I try to execute my tests:

```
Testing started at 17:23 ...
Installing br.com.foo
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/br.com.foo"
pkg: /data/local/tmp/br.com.foo
Success

Uploading file
    local path: F:\Android\CACS\cacs\cacs\build\outputs\apk\cacs-debug-androidTest-unaligned.apk
    remote path: /data/local/tmp/br.com.foo.test
Installing br.com.foo.test
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/br.com.foo.test"
pkg: /data/local/tmp/br.com.foo.test
Success    

Running tests
Test running started
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No instrumentation registered! Must run under a registering instrumentation.
at android.support.test.InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation(InstrumentationRegistry.java:45)
at br.com.bagger.inicio.MapaEnderecoTest.setUp(MapaEnderecoTest.java:35)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:191)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:176)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:554)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1701)

Finish
```

And this is the unique test that I am trying to run:

```
package br.com.doe.inicio;

import android.support.test.InstrumentationRegistry;
import android.support.test.espresso.Espresso;
import android.support.test.espresso.action.ViewActions;
import android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers;
import android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4;
import android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2;    
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;    
import br.com.foo.R;

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class MapaEnderecoTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MapaEndereco>
{    
    private MapaEndereco mActivity;

    public MapaEnderecoTest()
    {
        super(MapaEndereco.class);
    }

    @Override
    @Before
    protected void setUp() throws Exception
    {
        super.setUp();
        injectInstrumentation(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation());
        mActivity = getActivity();
    }

    @Test
    public void testeAbertura()
    {
        Espresso.onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.map)).perform(ViewActions.click());
    }
}
```

The error occurs right after the super.setUp() call, on the setUp method.

I have the instrumentation registered into the AndroidManifest file:

```
<instrumentation
        android:label="Multdex"
        android:name="com.android.test.runner.MultiDexTestRunner"
        android:targetPackage="br.com.foo"
        android:functionalTest="true"/>
```

And the problem I am facing is not the same as described here [NullPointer Exception when using Espresso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19558575/nullpointer-exception-when-using-espresso)

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Have you found a solution yet?

Comment: what version of the android gradle plugin are you using?

Comment: I'm using this plugin: classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0' @RicardoBelchior

Comment: @ThanasisPetsas Sadly I haven't solved yet. I have been thinking about debug the Android to find out what is going on

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem is with these gradle lines:

```
testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
testInstrumentationRunner "com.android.test.runner.MultiDexTestRunner"
```

You need a `MultiDexTestRunner`, but this class is derived from `InstrumentationTestRunner`. Your code needs a test runner that is derived from `AndroidJUnitRunner`

A solution is to create a custom `TestRunner` that extends `AndroidJUnitRunner` and implements the MultiDex code:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.multidex.MultiDex;
import android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner;

public class TestRunner extends AndroidJUnitRunner
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle arguments)
    {
        MultiDex.install(getTargetContext());
        super.onCreate(arguments);
    }
}
```

You only need to add a single Gradle line that references your custom `testInstrumentationRunner`. This will ensure that the build system generates the `AndroidManifest.xml` properties that are needed to run the tests with this runner.

Comment: Do you still need to have both testInstrumetationRunner ? and also the it declaration in manifest.xml ?

Comment: No, you only need the custom TestRunner. I only declared it in my build.gradle. When building, the manifest file gets generated in `Application/build/intermediates/manifest/androidTest/debug/` with the declaration in it. The Gradle toolset takes care of that.

Comment: It is unnecessary to create a custom TestRunner

Comment: Please provide a link to the same of the code and we see  where the `TestRunner` class was used. @KenVanHoeylandt

Comment: The perfect answer, thank you!, to bad google docs does not provide this information themselves.

Answer (score 10):

I had similar error and was struggling a lot to fix it. Although the accepted answer helped the OP, it did not solve my case, so I decided it is good if I record my solution here, hopefully it will help somebody else too.

My problem was that I was mixing `AndroidJUnit4`, `InstrumentationRegistry`, `ApplicationProvider` and `AndroidJUnitRunner`versions / packages. Make sure they all are of the same generation. These are the classes that made it all run for me:

- `androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner`
- `androidx.test.platform.app.InstrumentationRegistry`
- `androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4`
- `androidx.test.core.app.ApplicationProvider`

for these I needed the following in the `dependencies` part of my build.gradle

```
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:core:1.2.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.2.0'
```

And of course the correct

```
testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
```

in my `defaultConfig` of the `build.gradle`

Comment: I am getting this issue with Robolectric. Did you face it as well?[Robolectric] WARN: Android SDK 29 requires Java 9 (have Java 8). Tests won't be run on SDK 29 unless explicitly requested.

java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to create a Robolectric sandbox: Android SDK 29 requires Java 9 (have Java 8)

Comment: @android6p is completely different issue. I suggest we do not discuss it here, rather start a separate question for that. Overall, probably I will be able to help.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of:

```
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0'
```

I had to use a different library:

```
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
```

Comment: I don't recommend this, on the contrary everyone should use the new Android X libraries where possible.

Comment: I don't recommend it either, but in some cases migrating isn't practical. The OP was still using the support libraries. Trying to mix those with AndroidX dependencies caused the problem.