# Android. Where did ApplicationProvider go?

Tags: android, android-testing

I'm trying to run this line:

`Context context = ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext();`

Sample code such as https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/testing-db#java recommends it.

But I can't import ApplicationProvider (and I just LOVE how the documentation never imports anything, assuming your editor will prompt you correctly...). This line fails, with "error: package androidx.test.core.app does not exist":

`import androidx.test.core.app.ApplicationProvider;`

So where did ApplicationProvider go? I'm trying to use the current context to create a Room database:

```
        Context context = ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext();
        db = Room.inMemoryDatabaseBuilder(context, TestDatabase.class).build();
        userDao = db.getUserDao();
```

Comment: The answer apparently was to add a redundant line `testImplementation 'androidx.test:core:1.2.0'` to `build.gradle`. Now I'm on to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32957741/android-illegalstateexception-no-instrumentation-registered-must-run-under-a-re

Answer (score 29):

Add a redundant line `androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:core:1.2.0'` to `build.gradle`.

Comment: Good catch! https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/local-unit-tests#setup

Comment: Yeah it's not really redundant and you need `androidTestImplementation` instead of `testImplementation`.

Comment: But I am not able to access it in Local Unit Test Cases. I was using Robolectric library with RuntimeEnvironment.application. This says it's deprecated and the soultion is to use ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext(). But how do I access it in as the libraries marked with androidTestImplementation are accessible in androidTests (Instrumentation Test Cases) only. Please guide.

Comment: yabut you can't use any android whatsoever in a unit test, only raw Java, so if you need an Application Context, you need the entire Android stack and androidTests

Comment: It would be great if the [Android Room documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/testing-db#kotlin) included a mention to this import and library. Even though it is core there are many test libraries I did not have this one added prior to adding Room in my JUnit 5 tests.

Answer (score 5):

add
**androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:core:$version'** or
**testImplementation 'androidx.test:core:$version'**
dependency based on which type of test you do to your module-level gradle file.